# discrete distribution with no closed form of probability mass function

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Consider $$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}(x+e^{-x-1})}{(1-e^{-x-1})^2}$$ and $$p(x)=f(x)/\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}f(y),$$
$x$ non-negative integer.

Is this a known discrete distribution? A sort of generalization of the geometric distribution?

Comment: This doesn't look standard at all. $x$ and $e^{-x}$ side by side is especially unusual. Can you explain the origin ?

Comment: It is not so unusual, see for example "Discrete Shanker Distribution and Its Derived Distributions", http://medcraveonline.com/BBIJ/BBIJ-05-00140.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't call the Shanker distribution "usual".

Comment: I agree it isn't; however, a lot of papers have been published in recent years introducing "unusual" discrete distributions...

Comment: What is the definition of $f(y)$ ? Without knowing that you cannot say anything about $p(x)$.

Comment: $f(y)$ is defined above...